# Can I change the status files format?

Tags: data-loader, logging, status

I would like to ask if there is an option to change the format (delimiter) of the success/error log files of each Dataloader operation?
I could not find anything in the documentation, neither on the Web.

Thanks,

Jan

Answer (score 0):

There is no ability to change the delimiter.  You would need to fork the [repo](https://github.com/forcedotcom/dataloader) and modify the client to see if you can achieve this modification.

Thanks

Comment: Yeah, thought so, maybe I will create a script to change the delimiter.
Thank you for an answer.